# Is it possible to make a question feed that covers a whole site excluding certain tags?

Tags: support, feed

Over on [The Bridge](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge), badp created a separate feed for MW3 and Skyrim questions so we give them special attention.  You know, because of [this thing](http://skyrimvsmw3.com/).

Now, MW3 and Skyrim questions are already in the feed we have of *all* questions. The duplication is driving some users batty, and badp continues to repeat the mantra:

> If you can make a mw3 and skyrim free version of the questions feed, please do and give badp the URL to banish the duplicate question notifications away.

Currently, people are working around it by ignoring the users posting the special feeds, but that defeats the whole purpose.

So I have come here to ask, is it possible to make a mw3 and skyrim free version of the questions feed?  If so, how?

Comment: Yahoo! Pipes doesn't work. Yi Jiang tried and got time outs while retrieving the feeds. When I tried it in the past, it was just completely broken.